# Filtering out date in bash shell script from output of a command and not reading input from file

Tags: bash, date, filter, one-liner

The command is

```sh
sacct -u  -S 2021-07-01 -E 2021-08-01  --format=jobID,Submit -D
```

I have a command that I run in bash that gives output as follows (snapshot). It does not read from file

```
Job ID           Submit
128444           2021-07-01T10:12:30
127898           2021-06-09T03:45:30
127999           2021-06-21T16:45:20
129999           2021-07-15T11:30:29
131989           2021-07-31T01:20:30
```

I need to filter and show only job id in month of July, that is from 2021-07-01 to 2021-07-31 and not include June entries.

I tried awk but its not working.

```
sacct -u  -S 2021-07-01 -E 2021-08-01  --format=jobID,Submit -D |
awk '{print $2}'| awk '/^2021-07-01*/,/2021-07-31*/'
```

Is there a one liner that can do this?

Comment: `command | grep ' 2021-07-'`

Comment: *"I tried awk but its not working"*. Awk should be a good tool for this job. Add your attempts and explain what exactly did not work. [edit] your question. Do **not** post this as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

With sed

```
sed -nE 's/^([^ ]*).*-07-.*/\1/p'
```

or awk

```
awk -F'-| *' '$3=="07" {print $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression between the slashes needs to be a regular expression.

In a regex, `x*` means zero or more repetitions of `x`, not `x` followed by anything (like in a shell wildcard).

Also, your command would print *just_ the date, not the whole entry. (Piping Awk to Awk is usually pointless anyway; you would refactor the second Awk script into the first.)

```sh
sacct -u  -S 2021-07-01 -E 2021-08-01  --format=jobID,Submit -D |
awk '$2 ~ /^2021-07-/'
```

If you really only wanted to print the second field,

```sh
awk '$2 ~ /^2021-07-/ { print $2 }'
```

would do that; but then instead probably pass a different `---format` so that `sacct` doesn't print the field you don't care about.

If you wanted to keep the header line, you could add `NR==1` as an alternative condition for when to print.

```sh
sacct -u  -S 2021-07-01 -E 2021-08-01  --format=jobID,Submit -D |
awk 'NR == 1 || $2 ~ /^2021-07-/'
```

The text between the slashes is always a static regex. To match against a dynamic regex built from strings (which could change during your script's execution), try something like

```sh
sacct -u  -S 2021-07-01 -E 2021-08-01  --format=jobID,Submit -D |
awk -v yyyy_mm="$(date +%Y-%m)"  '$2 ~ "^" yyyy_mm "-"'
```

Comment: This does work, instead of hard coding dates  how do i  use variable in  awk, i tried the following but its not working . Just does not give anything as output        "awk -v year="$(date +%Y)" -v month="$(date +%m  -d '-1 month')"  'BEGIN  {$2  ~ /^year-month-/}'

Comment: Notice also how I get both the year and the month in one go; your attempt would get the future December of _this_ year rather than December of last year if you run it in January.